# Creating an object of a different class from a reference of a Different Class

Tags: java, stack, heap-memory

I am a newbie in Java.... It was all going smooth till I found that below scenario is possible in JAVA.

```
package newProject;

class A {
}
class B extends A {
    }

public class C {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
      A obj = new B();
    }
}
```

Can any one please explain me in detail about above scenario in terms of how is it possible and how it works on memory side

Comment: I think you have the code wrong. The B class definition should probably start with `public class B extends A`. I'd expect the code as-is to fail with type errors.

Comment: Please fix your braces and indentation.

Comment: Thanks folks.... I am not worrying about the Syntax here but the concept more...the idea behind the question is to understand how the memories take part in inheritance in the above case or in laymen terms how this works  internally

Answer (score 0):

As said before, this is **not** possible. However, it **is** possible when B extends A. This would mean that B has the same properties, methods etc as A + what you add onto it.

Answer (score 0):

you are allowed to do this

```
A obj = new B();
```

if one of the following conditions met:

- Class B must extends class A
- Class B implements the interface A

so, with the class definition you have is not possible!
now, suppose you have something like:

```
class A {
    void move(){...}
}
class B extends A {
    void start(){...}
    void dispose(){...}
}
A obj = new B();
```

the only valid method you can call is:

```
obj.move();
```

but since the object is a `new B` you can call all declared B methods but you need to cast

```
((B)obj).start();
```

Comment: I have edited my post now... Thanks.. Yes I meant in inheritance only. I have read that the address of the object gets stored in the reference variable of same classtype. For example : Consider `B obj = new B();`. B obj will create a variable by reference in STack memory with address of the object B ( new B()) in Heap memory.  So in stack the reference variable obj will have the value as XX101  (say the address of the heap memory object) .... But now how to fit above theory if my reference type becomes A

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay... thanks, check my update, I think it now explains better your edition...